# Primefaces doesn't recognize the value of the cell/field if I don't leave the cell/field.

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

I'm having this issue with saving data from the grid in PrimeFaces. When I set the value in the cell, and then change another and another cell, click here and there, and then I click on the save button, everything is working perfect. But if I miss to exit the cell (to change the focus), and just click the save button, the value from that last cell is lost.

Here is my cell:

```
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText style="text-transform: uppercase" value="#{bBean.someData}" /></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText style="text-transform: uppercase" value="#{bBean.someData}"  label="Some data">
                                </p:inputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
```

It looks like PrimeFaces is not able to recognize the change if some event is not fired.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now I fixed it for sure :)
I created a hidden button:

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" style="display:none !important" id="btn" value="SB"/>
```

and a javascript function that will simulate clicks on the hidden button:

```
function takefocus(){
                    $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:btn')).click();
                }
```

and I added to the save button, before calling save:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" onclick="takefocus();PF('waitDialog').show();saveData();"/>
```

and it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Giving your `<p:inputText>` `onmouseout` event you can additionally save value when user leaves cell with mouse pointer:
`<p:ajax event="mouseout" process="@this" partialSubmit="true"/>`

Comment: this one would do the thing as well.

Comment: Nope, nothing helps... :(

Comment: It worked for me, maybe you placed it inside `<p:cellEditor>` instead of `<p:inputText>`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for Firefox, but not for Chrome.
So if you find a better solution please share it here.

`<p:inputText onblur="triggerChange(this)... />`

`function triggerChange(el) {
    var e = jQuery.Event('keydown');
    e.which = 13;
    e.keyCode = 13;
    $(el).trigger(e);
}`

Comment: Thanks for the ansver. The problem is that it needs to work at least in chrome :)